# retrieve full data from foreign table with eloquent

Tags: eloquent, pivot

I've been reading some answers to similar questions here on the site, it seems everyone is trying to use a low level approach. The question is, shouldn't laravel and eloquent make it easy to solve stuff like that?
If I have a table with ids to two foreign tables, exmple `item_id` foreign of table `items` and `item_type_id` foreign of table `item_types`. How can I retrieve and join the data from these two tables directly instead of manually specifiying the id to look at in those foreign table and stuff?
Shouldn't eloquent have something like **"get data from foreign table given the ids that you found in pivot table and spit out the joined data"** ?

Answer (score 0):

### Laravel Eloquent: Relationships

I believe you should refer ***eloquent relationships***. It would help you to fetch datas from related datatables.

For Ex: We can have 2 to 3 three table `Users`, `Groups` & `user_group`(pivot table)

The `user_group` would have the relation between each user and various groups.

### In User Model

```
class User extends Eloquent
{
    public function groups()
    {
        return  $this->belongsToMany('Group', 'user_group', 'user_id', 'group_id');
    }
}
```

### In Group Model

```
class Group extends Eloquent
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Group', 'user_group', 'group_id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Now you can fetch a user and his relation with groups likewise:

```
$user_groups = User::find($user_id)->groups;
```

And to fetch the members of a group likewise:

```
$group_members = Group::find($group_id)->users;
```

*This code basically does the join in the backend.*

[Refer docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships) for deeper understanding.

Hope this would get you started.

Comment: yes, I know about that, the problem here is that the the table I am attaching to user has two foreign keys that refer to data contained in two other tables, what I need is the data inside those two foreign tables rather than the foreign keys.